# Most effective way to collect wifi bssid and rssi data across many windows platforms

Tags: windows, wifi, rssi, bssid

I'm trying to collect wifi Bssid and Rssi information on Windows, and am looking for the most reliable way to do that across as many versions of Windows as possible. With Vista it's easy using Win32 calls with the Wireless LAN API. That API exists on XP SP2 (sometimes) and SP3, but as far as I can tell it doesn't support gathering Bssid information on those platforms.

Ideally, I'd like a way to get it on all versions of XP. (I'm guessing there's just no hope at all for Windows 95 / 98 / ME). Any programming language or commandline tool will do. Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in that question. Could you link to the APIs that you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't get that information(from my understanding) from windows. I comes from the router itself. But Wireshark and nmap would be my guess.

Comment: windows is capable of providing that information if there is at least one wifi adapter in the system and the adapter is enabled, in this case you would ask the adapter to look for available networks and their bssid/rssi.

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct, Windows provides the possibility to get these information. The bad news: there is not ONE such way but different APIs and Interfaces which have to be used depending on the operating system.

But you do not have to re-invent the wheel, the libwlocate already contains the functions you are looking for: http://libwlocate.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libwlocate/libwlocate;a=tree;f=master;h=22427173ce6fa394bc6014d9f109f6ed12b9f25f;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command line tool,"netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid",I'v tried , it works on my Win7 original from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/187867/1767800
  However netsh wlan doesn't work on windows xp. And as the substitution you can try http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/how-capture-and-deploy-wlan-profiles on xp sp2 and sp3.