# Do something when Wi-Fi signal/connection is low ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on ASP .Net Core project.
Every time when the user try to do something or press some button I need to check WiFi status or connection or signal. In case that the status or connection or signal is low I want to save some info in session or cookies or maybe in DataBase.

I searched around and I found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/76024/check-internet-connection-available-or-not-in-c) as a potential solution. So I was thinking to do something like this :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
           if (connection == true)
           {
              //do nothing

           }
           else
           {
              //save some data
           }
       }
```

The problem is that if there is no WiFi signal, the program won't work and I can't save the data. So I need to save the data somehow before I lost the WiFi connection.

I allready read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/check-internet-connection/)  and [Detect wifi connectivity in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273967/detect-wifi-connectivity-in-c-sharp) ,but I have not found anything that maybe can help me. Also i saw that there are API that check WiFi connection, but I don't get it how to use it, and where should I call the method the check the WiFi status?
I haven't tried any of these solutions yet, and i don't know if it works.

Any suggestions or examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A website does not have access to the device to check the signal. The examples you found are for winforms/wpf.

Comment: The question would make no sense unless the *web server* uses a WiFi connection. Which is a pretty bad idea. Using a timer with a web app is complicated too as there's no desktop or single thread. Each request gets processed on a separate thread, using new instances of the controllers, webpages or razor pages used by the stack

Comment: The thing that has a WiFi connection is the *browser*. If you want the browser to handle connectivity, you'd have to write Javascript code that can handle intermittent disconnections. This means SPA, workers, local storage.

Comment: Or you could create a Blazor web app. Both Blazor Server and Blazor Wasm handle connectivity and local storage (up to a point) and attempt to reconnect

Comment: So I can't do it in ASP .NET ?

Comment: I once made something where if there was no connection then it wrote back to a cookie and then when it came back it wrote it back. I was using knockout and some knockout cookie plugin