# .NET: Reading the command prompt output

Tags: c#, command-line, netsh

I want to call the `netsh` command from .net, I am using the `Process` class to initiate the process which calls the `netsh` command, and its working fine, now I want to get the output returned by the `netsh` command in .NET, for example I am calling the below command in `Process`:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

this is returning me the list of active hostednetwork.

How can I read the list in .NET?
Can anyone assist me or take me to the right path (I don't want to use any third party tools)?

---

**UPDATES**
Below is my return output using netsh wlan show hostednetwork command

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "AqaMaula(TUS)"
Max number of clients  : 100
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Started
BSSID                  : 06:65:9d:26:f4:b7
Radio type             : 802.11n
Channel                : 11
Number of clients      : 1
    d0:c1:b1:44:8b:f0        Authenticated
```

Can anyone tell me how can i get all individual data and put them in database like, Mode, SSID Name, etc. (individually)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var output = RunProcess();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the process: starts it and waits upon its completion.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// Standart output content as a string.
    /// </returns>
    private static string RunProcess()
    {
        using (var process = CreateProcess())
        {
            process.Start();

            // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
            // For details, see: [Process.StandardOutput Property (System.Diagnostics)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx).
            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            return output;
        }
    }

    private static Process CreateProcess()
    {
        return new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = "netsh",
                        Arguments = "wlan show hostednetwork",
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true
                    }
            };
    }
}
```

## Update

I think you should use [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) framework instead of parsing results of command line utility. It is more reliable way. Take a look at the sources, they contain [WifiExample](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#213980).

Comment: @Abbas, please also take a look at [How do I get the available wifi APs and their signal strength in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496568/how-do-i-get-the-available-wifi-aps-and-their-signal-strength-in-net).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `StartInfo.UseShellExecute` to false and `RedirectStandardOutput` to true before starting the process, and then read from `Process.StandardOutput`.

All documented on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) property of the `Process` class.
The above linked MSDN page comes with a simple example of how to use `StandardOutput`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
//@param output The output captured from the netsh command in String format
//@param key The key you are trying to find (in your example "Mode")
public String getValue(String output, String key) {
    MatchCollection matches;
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(?<key>[A-Za-z0-0 ]+)\t\:\s(?<value>[.]+)");
    matches = rx.Matches(output);

    foreach (Match match in matches) {
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

        if (groups["key"] == key) {
            return groups["value"];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it atm to fix any small bugs.

Also, if you are going to reference them often, I'd place them into a Dictionary after parsing, to decrease lookup time.

Comment: can you give an example say for example i want to get the value of mode