# How to get the name of WiFi connection in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have been looking into the DeviceNetworkInformation class, and I have successfully used the following

•CellularMobileOperator 
•IsNetworkAvailable 
•IsCellularDataEnabled 
•IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled 
•IsWiFiEnabled

but I was wondering if there was a wayt o get the name of the WiFi connection, in addition to whether WiFi is enabled or not. I would like to be able to see the current name of the connection within my application. I have not seen where this was implemented, so is this actually possible? If so, how might I access such a property?

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// Find WIFI SSID
/// </summary>
private void FindWIFISSIDClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var network in new NetworkInterfaceList())
    {
        if ( (network.InterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) &&  (network.InterfaceState == ConnectState.Connected) )
            mLocatoinInfo.Text = network.InterfaceName; //Get the SSID of the WIFI
        else
            mLocatoinInfo.Text = "fail";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at this wrapper project with managed code in C# at [Managed Wifi API](http://www.codeplex.com/managedwifi).

References:

1. [How do I get the available wifi APs and their signal strength in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496568/how-do-i-get-the-available-wifi-aps-and-their-signal-strength-in-net)
2. [How to enumerate networks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706749(VS.85).aspx)
3. [How to get signal strength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706839.aspx)
4. [How to obtain WIFI access point information?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e17f69ec-1473-4142-882e-f812cc5f0948/)
5. [Wireless Network Scanner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19308/A-Vista-Wireless-Network-Scanner)

Comment: Question, would this work with Windows Phone 7, or possibly 8?