# View information on stored wifi profiles and keys

Tags: c#, windows-7, wifi

How can I get a list of stored wifi profiles, and their keys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496568/how-do-i-get-the-available-wifi-aps-and-their-signal-strength-in-net

Comment: this should point you in the direction you need: http://superuser.com/questions/148139/where-does-vista-windows-7-store-wireless-connection-information