# How can someone get the BSSID of a router without connecting to it?

Tags: wifi, router, ssid, bssid, kismet-wireless

1. How can someone get the BSSID of a router without connecting to it in order to differentiate between duplicate SSIDs?
2. Does a router broadcast the BSSID?

Answer (score 11):

Applying the command

```
netsh wlan show all
```

in windows would show details of all the routers including the BSSID in your wireless range, even though you might not have been connected to the router.

Answer (score 9):

You can get all the BSSID you have around with this command:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid
```

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS and macOS that's

```sh
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I
```

for the currently connected wifi, which you can also get by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> on the wifi menu.

To get a list of all hotspots/network available use

```sh
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
```

Comment: in the help page, it says `sudo` is required for getting the BSSID

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Linux and iwlist package** you can use

```
iwlist YOUR_INTERFACE scan
```

where YOUR_INTERFACE have to be an active wireless interface, typically wlan0.

And yes, a router working as an AP (it is the more common configuration) will send his BSSID.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo iwlist scanning
```

or filter(Address):

```
sudo iwlist scanning | grep Address
```

Answer (score 1):

in cmd: netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid (Windows 7)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your router is equal to WiFi access point。There are a bunch of ways to realize this in different operating system.
  1. In windows xp,you can install netstumbler;
  2. In windows ,you can use this cammand "netsh wlan show networks   mode=Bssid|findstr "BSSID" " as the post in https://stackoverflow.com/a/187867/1767800
  3. In linux, you can turn to netstumbler linux alternative kismet http://www.linuxalt.com/linux-alternatives-to/windows/netstumbler.html

All the software listed above show the detected BSSIDs and many other information to you by catching the beacon frame broadcast by the Access Point.